# Github actions: OpenIDConnect provider's HTTPS certificate doesn't match configured thumbprint

Tags: amazon-web-services, github-actions, amazon-iam

I'm currently working on a code that is placed on GitHub, and when we run the GitHub actions after pulling requests, we are receiving the following error because we have this deployment on AWS :enter image description here This error is recent, it didn't pop up until this Tuesday.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyWrq.png)

I've trying some things, like this information on this post from January: https://github.blog/changelog/2022-01-13-github-actions-update-on-oidc-based-deployments-to-aws/ But it didn't work, and one of my partners tried this other post https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_create_oidc_verify-thumbprint.html. but with no success. I don't know if this thumbprint got updated again recently, if anyone have any suggestion, I'm happy to receive them. Even if there is any shareable information that I can provide

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue recently with our aws stack deployed with AWS CDK and GitHub Actions. In our case updating the CDK version and redeploying solved the problem.